# $D_6$ is not a subset of $D_8$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I came across an example in Chapter-2 of Dummit and Foote(page-47) which says :$D_6$ is not a subgroup of $D_8$ ,the former is not even a subset of latter.I can't understand why is it not the subset of $D_8$?
How do we define one group as a subset of another?

Comment: can you figure out one element of $D_{6}$ that is not in $D_{8}$? Consider the prime factorization of 6 and 8, respectively.

Comment: I think many group theorists (including myself) would regard the statement "$D_6$ is a subset of $D_8$" as meaningless, because we think of $D_6$ as meaning any group isomorphic to the group of symmetries of the triangle rather than as any specific instance of the group. Even "the group of symmetries of the triangle" is not completely clear. Which triangle?

Comment: @DerekHolt If you define $D_n$ in a particular setting (symmetries of polygons), it looks meaningful to me. I'll have to check tonight, but D&F is probably doing this here. Group theorists have maybe the habit not to take this into account. However, notice that two isomorphic groups may have different properties, for example regarding transitive orbits: any group is isomorphic to a permutation group with a simply transitive action, simply take the action of the group on itself, and the elements are permutations of $(g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_n)$, with $g_i$ the original members of your group.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I agree with what you say, but I still think it's a very confusing, unhelpful, misleading and generally bad question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The statement "$D_6$ is not a subgroup of $D_8$" means there is no subgroup $H\subset D_8$ such that $D_6$ is isomorphic to $H$.  This is easy to verify as $D_6$ has an element of order $3$, but no subgroup of $D_8$ has an element of order $3$.

It is possible, though not particularly useful, to regard $D_6$ as a subset of $D_8$ set-theoretically.

Comment: I can't understand one thing that if otherwise I see elements of $D_6$ without checking subgroups of $D_8$,they are all contained in $D_8$.hence,$D_6$ must be subset of $D_8$ contradictory to the question.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract Elements of $D_6$ are not contained in $D_8$. They are two distinct sets.

Comment: @5xum I cannot understand it ,this means two different groups can never be explained in terms of one being subset of another.

Comment: @5xum i think that is only possible if both have the same binary operations and conditions.Please help where am I wrong.

Comment: That is why the answer by Kyle is absolutely perfect. We sometimes (mosto of the time, actually) shorten our notation and say that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ if it is isomorphic to a subgroup $H$ of $G$. And even in this way, $D_6$ is not a subgroup of $D_8$

Comment: The phrase "$H$ is a subgroup of $G$" can mean two things.  The first is the formal definition of being a subgroup, which requires that $H$ is a subset of $G$ while being closed under the group laws.  The second is looser, coming from the notion of groups being "the same up to isomorphism."  If there is a subset $H$ of $D_8$ which is isomorphic to $D_6$, then we would say $D_6$ is a subgroup of $D_8$, even though it, strictly speaking, isn't.

Comment: KyleMiller and 5xum,Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Kyle Miller I wanted to prove this statement :K is a subgroup of G if it is isomorphic to a subgroup H of G. can you please give some hint how to proceed?

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract The statement you are proving is incorrect in the strict sense of the word *subgroup* and is the *definition* of the more general term *subgroup*. In any case, it is not something you prove.

Comment: @5xum please clarify this- "The statement you are proving is incorrect in the strict sense of the word subgroup and is the definition of the more general term subgroup".

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract Strictly speaking, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ only if it is a subset of $G$ and a group. In this definition of the word, your statement is incorrect: $\mathbb Z_2$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_4$, but is not in itself a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_4$. Loosely speaking, $K$ is a subgorup of $G$ if it is isomorphic to one of its subgroups by definition (that is how we decide to use the word), so you can't really prove such a statement.

Comment: @5xum Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

$D_{2n}$ is usually defined as the group of symmetries of the regular $2n$-gon. That is $D_6$ acts on a hexagon, while $D_8$ acts on a octagon. You can write them down explicitly and see why $D_6$ is not a subset of $D_8$.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the case that ord $r$ in $D_6$ is 3, while ord $r$ in $D_8$ is 4, that's one reason why $D_6$ is not a subgroup of $D_6$.